# Blender 2.91 constantly crashing in Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: 3d, blender

I got myself an used computer, HP Compaq Elite 8300 MT, with Intel Core i5-3470 CPU@ 3.20Hz x 4. It already had Windows 10 installed. The first thing I did was test out my Blender (v. 2.91) over 5 million triangle character with textures and materials. The camera was able to rotate just fine.

Then I replaced Windows 10 with 64-bit Ubuntu 20.04.1, reinstalled Blender 2.91 again, and this time the camera was considerably laggy when using the same blend file. However, it worked with considerably less lag (tough not completely without) when on solid mode (materials and textures disabled). The current graphics card is Nvidia 137.

When I first booted Ubuntu I admittedly had issues with resolution, and tried a few graphics and resolution-related command lines (such as `xrandr`) to fix them. And unfortunately I can't quite recall everything I did.

In any case, do you guys have ideas on why Blender is slower in Ubuntu? The hardware is the same and I know Ubuntu faster than Windows 10, so I'd like this solved soon as possible. If this background info isn't enough feel free to ask more.

EDIT: The situation is worse than I tought. Even when handling relatively simple models Blender keeps crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution! Just had to start the Software Update Manager, go to Additional Drivers, and change to nvidia-driver-450.