Blender 2.82 Crashing on Ubuntu 20.04
I have installed blender 2.82 on Linux, on my VM. The installation was smooth with no issues, but when I open the app it is lagging. On top of that, the moment I try to do a simple task it crashes. My last attempt was to make the file on Windows and send it just in case I could simply load it, but the issue remained.
I got the following error message:
Code error
Warning: property 'release_confirm' not found in keymap item 'OperatorProperties'
Read blend: /home/angel/Dowonloads/untitled.blend
Color management: scene view 'AgX' not found, setting default 'Standard'.
Error, region type 14 missing in - name: 'View3D', id:1
Error, region type 15 missing in - name: 'View3D', id:1
Writing: /tmp/untitled.crash.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

This is the error I get when I simply try to do anything.
Warning: property 'release_confirm' not found in keymap item 'OperatorProperties'
blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x37) [0x565280b56897]
blender(trans_mesh_customdata_correction_init+0x3af) [0x56527ebd0bdf]
blender(+0x1b42a30) [0x56527ebb8a30]
blender(transformEvent+0xe80) [0x56527ebbbd80]
blender(+0x1b6eb7c) [0x56527ebe4b7c]
blender(+0x15d49ca) [0x56527e64a9ca]
blender(+0x15d57b4) [0x56527e64b7b4]
blender(+0x15d73ec) [0x56527e64d3ec]
blender(wm_event_do_handlers+0x50d) [0x56527e64dc6d]
blender(WM_main+0x20) [0x56527e643160]
blender(main+0x2b6) [0x56527e4163d6]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7f28e0bd1083]
blender(_start+0x2e) [0x56527e4648ae]
BLI_assert failed: /build/blender-RL3axj/blender-2.82.a+dfsg/source/blender/editors/transform/transform_convert_mesh.c:1033, trans_mesh_customdata_correction_init(), at 'tc->custom.type.data == ((void *)0)'
Aborted (core dumped)


From your question. I have installed blender on Linux 2.82 on my VM. What is Linux 2.82?

Please cut and paste the code error into the question not as a link. Please use edit to add it to the question.

Sorry about that I made a typo. I meant Blender 2.82 like I mention in the title

possibly related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277677/blender-2-91-constantly-crashing-in-ubuntu-20-04-1
